# Kivy Python - wrong color using kivy.utils.rgba

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I try to convert my *hex number* which informs about a color using *kivy.utils.rgba* method but it converts to incorrect color.

I mean, I created a sample view in *Inkspace* and took the code in *hexdecimal representation* from there and then inserted it into the code but the visible color in Inkspace editor is different than in the created application in Kivy. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<FlatButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    font_size:  16
<SigninWindow>:
    id:                 main_win
    orientation:        "vertical"
    spacing:            150
    space_x:            self.size[0]/3
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:       utils.rgba('17b61738')
        Rectangle:
            size:       self.size
            pos:        self.pos
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y:    None
        height:         50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:       (.06,.45,.45,1)
            Rectangle:
                size:       self.size
                pos:        self.pos
        Label:
            text:           "Nazwa aplikacji"
            bold:           True
            size_hint_x:    .9
        FlatButton:
            text:           "x"
            size_hint_x:    .1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:        "vertical"
        padding:            main_win.space_x, 10
        spacing:           
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:    "vertical"
            spacing:        10
            size_hint_y:    None
            height:         100
            Label:
                id:                 info
                text:               ''
                markup:             True
                size_hint_y:        None
                height:             20
            TextInput:
                id:                 username_field
                hint_text:          "Username"
                multiline:          False
                focus:              True
                on_text_validate:   pwd_field.focus = True
            TextInput:
                id:                 pwd_field
                hint_text:          "Password"
                multiline:          False
                password:           True
                on_text_validate:   root.validate_user()
        Label:
            id:             sp
            size_hint_y:    None
            height:         40
        Button:
            text:               "Sign In"
            size_hint_y:        None
            height:             40
            background_color:   (.06, .45, .45, 1)
            background_normal:  ''
            on_release:         root.validate_user()
        Label:
            id:     sp2
```

Comment: Are you sure that the color in Inkspace was an RGB color and not some other format?

Comment: @JohnAnderson yes, I am sure it was RGBA format.

Answer (score 0):

If the color you are talking about is the `utils.rgba('17b61738')`, then the opacity of that color is `0.21` (meaning that it is mostly transparent). So the color that is displayed is mostly the background showing through, with a little greenish tint. So, you should check what color the background is in your Inkspace image. You can then insert another `Rectangle` (before the one in question) with the correct background color. That should duplicate the desired color (assuming that the new `Color` has opacity of 1).